# Ensuring Lorenz Gauge condition in Green Function solution

Tags: potential, gauge-theory, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, gauge

In the Lorenz Gauge, we can write Maxwell's equations as:
$$\tag1 \Box A^\beta=\mu_0j^\beta.$$

We then go on to solve this by treating each component $A^\beta$ as an independent solution of the scalar wave equation with source, and summing Green functions.  That is:
$$\tag2 A^\beta=\mu_0\int \frac{1}{4\pi |r-r'|}j^\beta(ct-|r-r'|, r')\ \mathrm d^{3}r'.$$

My question is, how have we ensured that the Lorenz gauge condition is still met?

Sure to write $(1)$, we needed $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$, but how have we ensured our solution $(2)$ meets this condition?

Comment: Hint: what is $\partial_\mu j^\mu$? [also, its easier if you write $(2)$ in terms of $\mathrm dt'\mathrm d^3r'$]

Comment: I thought that you were still struggling so I decided to post a more detailed hint. I'm glad you could solve it on your own though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch of the argument:

1. Write your equation in the form
   $$
   A^\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^4} G(x-x')j^\mu(x')\ \mathrm dx'
   $$
   where $G$ is one of the [propagators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Causal_propagators) of the wave equation. For example, $G_\mathrm{ret}(x)\propto\delta(x^2)\Theta(x^0)$ which, after integration over $\mathrm dx^0$, leads to your second formula.
2. Show that
   $$
   \partial_\mu A^\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^4} G(x-x')\partial'_\mu j^\mu(x')\,\mathrm dx'
   $$
   where we have use the fact that $G$ depends only on the difference $x-x'$, and we have integrated by parts. Here one should argue that boundary terms vanish because of the kinematics of $G$.
3. Argue by [current conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserved_current) that the Lorenz gauge condition holds. One should note that, independently of the chosen gauge,
   $$
   \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=j^\nu
   $$
   and therefore, due to the skew-symmetry of $F$, the current *must* be conserved, as a consistency condition for the above PDE to be well-posed.